# Wrong type argument: symbolp, 10

Tags: functions, variables, quote, symbols

I would like create function that ask me how length I want the Pomodoro but it say wrong type argument.

```
(defun changePomoLength ()
  (interactive)
  (set-variable org-pomodoro-length (read-string "How longth: "))
  )
```

When I open set-variable function description.
it signature is

```
(set-variable VARIABLE VALUE &optional MAKE-LOCAL)
```

VALUE is a LISP Object, is string read from (read-string) function not count as LISP object?
how to make my string became LISP object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VARIABLE` is a variable, that is, a symbol.

Instead of passing a symbol as the first argument, you passed its value.

`set-variable` is a function, not a macro or special form. It first evaluates each of its arguments, then acts on their values. The first argument you passed is `org-pomodoro-length`. That is, because the args get evaluated, you passed the **value** of `org-pomodoro-length` - which apparently is not a symbol. Hence the error.

This is probably what you wanted - note the quote mark:

```lisp
(defun changePomoLength ()
  (interactive)
  (set-variable 'org-pomodoro-length (read-string "How longth: ")))
```

Comment: this solution work (I try enter 15) but I got another error when running orrg-pomdoro.

```user-error: Value ‘"15"’ does not match type integer of org-pomodoro-length```

is this mean that I should not save the variable as string?
can you help me again how to save org-pomdoro-length as integer?

Comment: Nevermind, I change ```(read-string)``` to ```(read)``` and it work, thank you very much.